# Storyboard animation not completing when triggering property changes

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard

I am using WPF and MVVM. I have a storyboard with a color animation triggering on some state in the ViewModel. If in the "Increased" state the storyboard will cause the item to flash green once. If in the "Decreased" state the storyboard will flash red once. If in the "Unchanged" state nothing will happen.

The problem I am having is if for any reason the state changes while the animation is running the animation will stop. E.g. I enter the the Increased state and the animation begins to flash green. Then the same property changes to Unchanged and the animation ceases immediately without ending.

**Is there a way to have the animation run its course even though the value on which it is triggering has changed?**

```
<Storyboard x:Key="ValueIncreasedStoryboard" AutoReverse="True">
    <ColorAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
        To="{StaticResource ResourceKey=IncreasedColor}"
        Duration="0:0:0.4" />
    <ColorAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
        To="{StaticResource ResourceKey=IncreasedColor}"
        Duration="0:0:1" />
</Storyboard>

<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Value="{x:Static ViewModel:Status.Increased}">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ValueIncreasedStoryboard}" x:Name="ValueIncreased_Storyboard"/>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ValueIncreased_Storyboard"/>
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

**SOLUTION:
A combination of deleting the exit action and setting the fill behavior to Stop.**

Comment: Surelly, just do not use triggers and implement it by hands

Comment: The triggers are in a style which is used several times.

Comment: What happens if you remove `ExitActions`?

Comment: This fixes the issue but introduces another. Now because of the lack of the RemoveStoryboard call sometimes the animation doesn't clear (the color stays red).

Comment: Then subscribe the animation`s `Completed` event and clear it there

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. I tried calling the stop command on the storyboard but this doesn't clear the color. Is there a way to call RemoveStoryBoard?

Comment: Wrote an answer to avoid discussion here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this lines:

```
<DataTrigger.ExitActions>
    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ValueIncreased_Storyboard"/>
</DataTrigger.ExitActions>
```

Then subscribe to Storyboard.Completed event. You may do it from XAML using EventSetter.
In Completed event handler remove storyboard.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Doesn't the RemoveStoryboard action actually have to run? I cannot find a way to actually trigger the action.

Comment: I don't even think the Storyboards coming through on the Completed event are the Storyboards with the error. I tried storyboard.Remove() as well.

Comment: Okay, does the debugger stop on the breakpoint in the Completed event handler? I`ve got one more idea to write event trigger executed by the Completed event and use RemoveStoryboard in its EnterActions. But it seems to be impossible :(

Comment: It is hitting on the Completed event. So the storyboard does complete. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Have you tried [FillBehavior property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior.aspx) `<ColorAnimation
 FillBehavior="Stop"`?